# OpenGL Buffer Usage for both reading and writing

Tags: opengl, buffer

While the usage flag in OpenGL's `glBufferData` Function is known for being just a hint and not a real restriction, the documentation says that "DRAW" is for "User writes to it and then uses it to pass as an argument to other OpenGL functions." and "READ" is "This buffer will be filled with data from the GL and the user wants to read from it." but what if I want, just as a hypothetical useage, use the GPU as external storage and simply write and later read from the same buffer (maybe after the GL has made changes to it)?

The bit-values of these constants do not suggest that I can combine them (like `GL_DYNAMIC_READ | GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`).

Is there any "best" usage flag I can use to hint the GL as to "I want to use that buffer as storage to read and write from"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what if I want, just as a hypothetical useage, use the GPU as external storage and simply write and later read from the same buffer (maybe after the GL has made changes to it)?

Then either you stop caring about the usage hint or you don't use OpenGL. OpenGL's buffer objects exist for the purposes of OpenGL's usage. They aren't there to give you access to a new pool of memory to play around with.

*Especially* since that "pool of memory* may very well be the same pool of memory `malloc` et. al allocates from. And there's nothing you can do in OpenGL to ensure that a buffer object's storage comes from GPU memory (or to even check if the GPU has dedicated memory).

In short, this is not a usage pattern OpenGL exists to support, and therefore it doesn't support it very well.

Comment: Though wasn't OpenGL "misused" as a parallel computation solution before OpenCL was introduced to basically do exactly that? Maybe you know something from that time back in the day oh mighty dragongod.

Comment: @salbeira: "*Though wasn't OpenGL "misused" as a parallel computation solution before OpenCL was introduced to basically do exactly that?*" No. Compute operations use GPU operations to read from or write to that buffer. Yes, the CPU may read from or write to that buffer as well, but the purpose of those reads is to read compute results, and the purpose of the writes is to write source compute data. What *you* are talking about is just using buffers for additional CPU storage. That's not its purpose.